# Is there any solution to find a condition for $f(x)=a+bx^n+cx^2-dx>0$ to always hold true?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality

Okay, I am interested to know the criteria for a function to always hold $$f(x)=a+bx^n+cx^2-dx>0,$$
if it is given that $a, b, c>0$ and $n\in(-2,2)$ is some real number and $x>0$.  My idea was to find a minima of this function, and at minima $x_m$, the following condition has to be satisfied $$nbx_m^{n-1}+2cx_m-d=0,$$ and the function exhibits minima only when $$n(n-1)x_m^{n-2}>-2c.$$
Now to find a condition when $f(x)>0$ is always satisfied, my idea would be to find $x_m$ from second equation and replace it in the first equation. The problem is second equation is not solvable except for some special values of $n$. So my question is it this the dead end or there is something more that can be done to approach towards the solution? Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can see that $f(x) = (cx^2-dx+a) + (bx^n)$. The first expression is a quadratic function $q$, and you know its graph is a parabola that opens upwards (because $c>0$). If you can show that the portion of the parabola over the positive x-axis lies above the x-axis, then $f>0$, being the sum of two positive values (since also $b>0$). For example, if the vertex lies above the x-axis, or if the vertex is to the left of the y-axis (the latter suffices because $(0,q(0))=(0,a)$ and this point would be on the rising side of the parabola).

Comment: Is $n\in\{-2,2\}$ (the set containing two numbers, $-2$ and $2$) or $(-2,2)$ (the open interval of $\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: It is open interval in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For positive and rational $n = \frac{p}{q}$ we can do the substitution $z = w^q$ and reduce this problem to a checking if polynomial is non-negative. It is known that univariate polynomial is non-negative iff it is a [sum of squares](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-972-algebraic-techniques-and-semidefinite-optimization-spring-2006/lecture-notes/lecture_10.pdf) . I am not sure if I will be able to solve this to the end, but maybe someone would be interested to pick the idea.

Comment: using descartes rule of sign prove that d=0. then you may proceed easily.

Answer (score 1):

Take, for example, the case  $f(x) = x^6+x^2-x + a$.  Here $f$ is convex, with a minimum at the real root $r$ of $f'(x) = 6 x^5 + 2 x - 1$, which happens to be approximately $.4466635719$.  The condition to have  $f(x) > 0$ for all $x>0$ is $a > -r^6 - r^2 + r$.  It can be shown that $-r^6 - r^2 + r$ is a root of the polynomial $  -{z}^{5}-{\frac {8\,{z}^{3}}{27}}+{\frac {25\,{z}^{2}}{27}}-{\frac {
5881\,z}{11664}}+{\frac{1127}{15552}}
$, which has Galois group $S_5$ and is not solvable by radicals.  So unless you can solve quintic equations, you won't be find an explicit necessary and sufficient condition for your problem.  Of course you can find approximate solutions, e.g. by using numerical methods to approximate the roots of $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial case: $d\le 0$, the inequality is always satisfied. 
Therefore we assume always $d>0$.

The general case independent of $n$ we get with the maximum of $h(x):=xd-cx^2$ :

$h^\prime(x)=0$ => maximum of $h(x)$ is $h(\frac{d}{2}) =\frac{d^2}{4c}$

The inequality above is always fulfilled with $a+bx^n>\frac{d^2}{4c}$.

Therefore: Should the inequality valid for all $x>0$, then it has to be $d^2\le 4ac$.

Now the cases depending on $n$ because of $d^2>4ac$.

$n=0$ or $n=1$: quadratic equation  (not a problem to discuss)

Therefore: $n\in (-2,+2)\setminus\{0,1\}$

A note at the beginning:
$a+x(bx^{n-1}+cx)>dx$ means, that the inequality is always fulfilled with $bx^{n-1}+cx\ge d$, therefore the cases $0<bx^{n-1}+cx<d$ and $bx^{n-1}+cx\ge d$ have to be discussed.

$n>1$: It doesn’t exist any extremum for $bx^{n-1}+cx$, no criteria can be given independent of $x$.

$n<1$: We get no maximum, only a minimum. => No criteria for $0<bx^{n-1}+cx<d$, but interesting for the other case.

$(bx^{n-1}+cx)^\prime=(n-1)bx^{n-2}+c:=0$ => $x=(\frac{-c}{b(n-1)})^{\frac{1}{n-2}}$ with $\frac{-c}{b(n-1)}>0$

We put the result into $bx^{n-1}+cx\ge d$ and therefore the criteria for the inequality is
$c\frac{n-2}{n-1}(\frac{-c}{b(n-1)})^{\frac{1}{n-2}}\ge d$.

So, I hope that I have calculated right and it helps.

EDIT: Calculation corrected.

EDIT 2: The case $c\to 0^+$ means $c:=0$ and therefore $f(x)=a+bx^n-dx$.

Extremum (here: minimum): $f^\prime(x)=nbx^{n-1}-d:=0$ => $x=(\frac{d}{nb})^\frac{1}{n-1}$.

This can only exist for $n>0$. We put this result into the inequality and get the condition $a>d\frac{n-1}{n}(\frac{d}{nb})^\frac{1}{n-1}$. For the special case $0<n<1$ is $f(x)>0$ valid independent of $b$ and $d$.

For $n<0$ we always have a solution for $f(x)=0$. This means with $f(x_0)=0$, that we get $f(x_0)>0$ only for $x<x_0$.

Comment: $a$ is an important parameter that should set the condition. For instance if $a$ is very large in comparison to $b$, $c$ and $d$, then the condition is always satisfied. Therefore, I am not sure if your criteria is good.

Comment: I think, you mean the case $a\ge\frac{d^2}{4c}$. Here it depends on $a$. But maybe this criteria is too rough ?

Comment: Can you find a counterexample, which contradicts the criterias above ?

Comment: well one immediate limitation of your answer is the case when $c\rightarrow 0^+$. Then, the condition that you gave is really crude. As a side note: in the limit when $c\rightarrow 0^+$, one can obtain an exact condition by following the steps I outlined in the problem itself.

Comment: For $c=0$ your second equation shows, that the minimum $x_m$ can only exist for $n>0$. Because of the need of case distinctions the answer to your general question seems to be No.

Comment: Addition: Has always to be $x>0$ or is also $x>x_0>0$ valid, where $x_0$ depend on $a,b,c,d$ ? In the second case it's enough to find an implizit condition for the parameters.

Comment: $x>0$ is the only thing we know about $x$.

Comment: I have added the case $c:=0$.